# Multiple useSelector overlaps DOM in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

I am using two useSelector and surprisingly it overrides the previous state which it is not supposed to happen.

```
import { fetchProduct } from "features/ProductSlice";
import { fetchCategory } from "features/ProductCategorySlice";

const ProductList = () => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const { data: products, status } = useSelector((state) => state.product)

    const { data: categories } = useSelector((state) => state.productCategory)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                await Promise(dispatch(fetchProduct()))
                dispatch(fetchCategory());
            } catch (error) {
                // handle or ignore errors?
            }
        };

        fetchData();
    }, [dispatch]);

    console.log('from list p ', products.length)
    console.log('from list c ', categories.length)

    ... 
}
```

Reducer Code:

ProductSlice: https://codefile.io/f/5HjRcFqvLWoutajPIJLq

ProductCategorySlice: https://codefile.io/f/IQLrLy6xC4gALqj254j7

Video Demo: https://screenrec.com/share/IcJyYuvsKU

As the product categories are fetched first, the value of products update with the value of categories (which is weird). Next when products are fetched then products update again. However the products should not update twice and should only update when products data arrives.

The value of console log is same for both cases.

Looking for the kind help !!

Comment: seconding @timotgl.  The code that is posted here is not the problem.  There is a mistake somewhere in your reducer or thunks.  Either A) you are mutating the state or B) you are storing the results of `fetchCategory` and `fetchProduct` to the same place in your state, causing one to override the other.

Comment: @LindaPaiste i posted the link of the thunk / reducer code. kindly have a look. Now the overlap issue solved partially, which means it doesn't overlaps if I load page of ProductList. But If I visit ProductCategoryList and then navigate to ProductList it overlaps the  products data with product categories data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for editing in the slice and thunk code -- that's where your problem is!

Every `createAsyncThunk` must have a **unique** action name.  These thunks are not part of the slice itself, so they don't get automatically prefixed with the slice name in the way that actions created from your `reducers` would.   You should add in the prefix yourself, using action names like `'productCategory/fetch'` and `'product/fetch'` to keep them distinct.

(The exact names don't matter.  You could use `'fetchCategory'` and `'fetchProduct'`.  You just need to make sure that they are different from each other.)

Right now your `fetchCategory` and `fetchProduct` thunks will both dispatch actions with `type` `'fetch/pending'`, `'fetch/fulfilled'`, etc. so they will both match each other's actions and save data to each other's state.

---

change

```
export const fetchCategory = createAsyncThunk(
    'fetch',
    async () => {
```

to

```
export const fetchCategory = createAsyncThunk(
    'productCategory/fetch',
    async () => {
```

Comment: Exactly !! this is the mistake you mentioned I was doing. Now it is working. Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

> As the product categories are fetched first, the value of products update with the value of categories (which is weird).

This is something you need to debug in your reducers. If fetching categories only writes to `state.productCategory` which is separate from `state.product`, then this shouldn't happen.

Are you sure that by "update" you mean you see `products.length` being logged with a different value? Because if it's just printing the same value, that's ok. You shouldn't make assumptions about how often the body of your function component is invoked, calling the console.log.